# How to run PostgreSQL commands inside docker container from host?

Tags: postgresql, docker, psql, docker-exec

I need to run a bunch of PostgreSQL commands/queries running as a Docker container. I have something similar in MySQL which works but I can't seem to figure out a way to do the same for a PostgreSQL database:

```bash
# MySQL
docker exec $CONTAINER mysql -u$MYSQL_USER -p$PASSWORD -e "USE $DATABASE;"
```

When I tried something similar for PostgreSQL:

```bash
# PostgreSQL
docker exec -i db psql -h localhost -U postgres -d app -e "SELECT * FROM users;"
```

I get the following error:

> psql: warning: extra command-line argument "SELECT * FROM users;" ignored

Comment: Looks like it's supposed to be `-c` instead of `-e`.

Comment: You should be able to just run `psql` from the host, connecting to the first port number you specified in a `docker run -p` option.  You do not need `docker exec` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you launch your PostgreSQL container like this:

```bash
docker run --rm --name postgres -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d postgres
```

You can submit a query directly using `psql` in the container:

```bash
docker exec -i postgres psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "SELECT * FROM pg_user;"
```

You can also just submit a query directly from the host. Note that you need to expose a port when you launch your PostgreSQL container using `-p 5432:5432`.

```bash
export PGPASSWORD='password'
psql -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres -c "SELECT * FROM pg_user;"
```

[image]